# clarification of math notation

Tags: functions, notation, special-functions, random-functions

0
down vote
favorite

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding what this notation is saying exactly and hoping someone could work it out.

```
Let F: {0,1}^k -> {{0,1}^k -> {0,1}^k}, k-> F_k be a pseudo random function .
```

From what I gather, F is a function that takes in a string of 0,1 of length k. it then transforms that string but its that transformation I am confused by

Comment: $F(k)=F_k$ is defined to be a transformation itself. This means that every string is transformed into a transformation of strings.

Comment: You are correct, but I don't get exactly what what , in this context, that means.

so is it just a two step transformation ?

Meaning if i were to put in 101 , would something like this be happening,

101 -> 100 -> 011  
  
where 011 would be the output of F(101)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it takes in a $k$-bit integer (the seed, presumably), and returns a function that maps $k$-bit integer inputs to $k$-bit integer outputs.  (So it's more a pseudo-random function *generator* than the pseudo-random function itself; given the same seed, it produces the same pseudo-random function.)  Without more context, it's a bit difficult to say for sure.

Comment: I believe that you are correct; but the definition of F is still confusing to me.  If for instance i was to put in F(101) as input, I don't see what the {{0,1}^k -> {0,1}^k} is actually doing.

Comment: @razeal113: Let's say $G$ is a pseudo-random function.  That means that $G$ is a function that takes in a $k$-bit integer input as an index, and returns a pseudo-random $k$-bit integer as output.  So if $k = 2$, let's say, then we might have $G(00) = 10, G(01) = 11, G(10) = 10, G(11) = 00$.  (Note that $G$ is not bijective.)  $F$ is then a "meta" function that takes as input a $k$-bit integer as a seed, and returns "a different $G$" for each seed value.